# How to remove 'index.php' from permalinks [WordPress on Composer]

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, composer-php, permalinks

I have local server, on which I'm running WordPress with Composer.

After database migration from my local to AWS RDS, the permalinks changed it's behaviour: now there's 'index.php' in the beginning of tags, like:

> http://example.com/**index.php**/name-of-page

Also, in the *wp-admin->Settings->Permalinks* the structure is custom now:

> /index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

Details about my local server:

- Xubuntu 18
- Apache2
- AllowOverride All for both `/` and `var/www/`
- it's on Composer, with custom dir (wp-content is seperated from wp core)
- .htaccess:

  ```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /project/public/wp/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /project/public/wp/index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

  # END WordPress
  ```

---

What I have tried:

http://dejanjanosevic.info/remove-index-php-permalink-in-wordpress/

http://derekmolloy.ie/remove-index-php-from-your-wordpress-url/

- updating permalinks
- updating composer
- selling my soul to Satan

---

What are the results?

Modyfying .htaccess has no effect - just ends in 404, the only links that work are still the ones that include `/index.php/`. Updating permalinks from WordPress has same result.

I'm running out of ideas here.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it.

For anyone looking for a solution to the same problem, here's guide:

1. Change permalink settings in wp-admin to pretty permalinks
2. Install mod_rewrite module in apache
3. **The most important part**, in etc/apache/apache2.conf (NOTE THAT YOU **MUST CHANGE** THE NAME OF FOLDER):

   ```
   <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #<Directory /srv/>
    #  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #  AllowOverride None
    #  Require all granted
    #</Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/html/NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>*
   ```

   4. Restart apache